# Reduction of Order for two 2nd Order ODEs to a system of four 1st order ODE with Initial Conditions and sine functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reduction-of-order-ode

I am trying to determine how to turn these two 2nd order ODEs into a system of four 1st order ODEs with initial conditions. Afterwards, I am to turn it into a matrix.

eqn 1:
$$3.2\theta''_1 + 1.44[\cos(\theta_2-\theta_1)]\theta''_2 - 1.44[\sin(\theta_2-\theta_1)]\theta'^2_2+62.784\sin(\theta_1)=0$$

eqn 2:
$$1.08\theta''_2+1.44[\cos(\theta_2-\theta_1)]\theta''_1+1.44[\sin(\theta_2-\theta_1)\theta'^2_1+17.658\sin(\theta_2)=0$$

Initial Conditions:
$$\theta_1(0)=0.2 rad$$ $$\theta'_1(0)=0.4 rad/s$$
$$\theta_2(0)=0.3 rad$$ $$\theta'_2(0)=0.5 rad/s$$

I have tried doing some variable substitution, but it has not gotten me anywhere. What stumps me the most is the variables being embedded within a sine function $\sin(\theta)$ and the $\theta'^2$ as I have never come across it before in my diff eq classes. Does this also require some sort of Laplace Transform?

Comment: This is not reduction-of-order as the term is commonly used (esp. for linear equations), but an equivalent first-order system.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your ODE in the following form:
$$
  \begin{pmatrix}
    3.2 & 1.44[\cos(\theta_2-\theta_1)] \\
    1.44[\cos(\theta_2-\theta_1)] & 1.08
  \end{pmatrix}
  \vec \theta''
  = \vec f(\vec\theta,\vec\theta'),
$$
where $f(\ldots)$ encompasses all of the other terms you show.

If you denote the matrix by $A(\vec\theta)$, then you can multiply through with $A^{-1}$ to obtain
$$
  \vec \theta''
  = A(\vec\theta)^{-1} \vec f(\vec\theta,\vec\theta'),
$$
and now you can probably see where this is going: If you introduce $\vec\psi=\vec\theta'$, you can rewrite the differential equation in first order form as
$$
  \vec\theta' = \vec\psi
\\
  \vec \psi'
  = A(\vec\theta)^{-1} \vec f(\vec\theta,\vec\psi).
$$
This is the desired first order form.

Comment: How would the $f(\vec\theta,\vec\theta')$ be expressed?

Comment: It has all of the terms with zero or one derivatives in your original question, except that I brought those terms to the right hand side.